# AspectJ can't work on Scala function literal?

Tags: scala, aspectj, function-literal

I have the following scala class and annotated aspectj class:

```
package playasjectj

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before

class Entity {
    def foo(p:String):String ={
      return p
    }
    def bar(handler:(String,String,Long)=>String):Unit={
        handler("first", "second", 100L)
    }
}

object Entity {
  def main(args:Array[String]){
     val inst = new Entity
     inst.foo("we are the champion")
     val handler = (first:String, second:String, value:Long) => {
          first + second + ":" + value
     }
     inst.bar(handler)
  }
}

@Aspect
class EntityAspect{

    @Pointcut("execution(* foo(String) ) && target(playasjectj.Entity) && args(p)")
    def pointcut_foo(p:String):Unit={}

    @Pointcut("execution(* bar(scala.Function3<String,String,Long,String>)) && target(playasjectj.Entity) && args(handler)")
    def pointcut_bar(handler: (String,String,Long)=>String):Unit={}

    @Before("pointcut_foo(p)")
    def beforeAdvice_foo(p:String):Unit={
        println("before advice foo: "  + p)
    }

    @Before("pointcut_bar(handler)")
    def beforeAdvice_bar(handler:(String,String,Long)=>String):Unit={
        println("before advice bar:")
    }

}
```

function bar works well, but function foo doesn't. There is no any errors, seems the execution of function "foo" is not caught.

[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.5 built on Thursday Jan 29, 2015 at 01:03:58 GMT

[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@14dad5dc

[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] info using configuration /Users/grant/programming/java/workspace/playasjectj/bin/META-INF/aop.xml

[AppClassLoader@14dad5dc] info register aspect playasjectj.EntityAspect
before advice foo: we are the champion

Anyone knows how to solve the problem? I guess it is related to how scala transform the tuple into java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by myself. the problem is not function literal, but type "Long". If I use "java.lang.Long" in that situation, that works. for generic type, AspectJ expects "Type",not primitive. in Scala, numeric type values like Int, Long, even Boolean are equivalent to java primitive type